# Active Image size Woocommerce Product page

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce

Hi guys I have a problem. On my product page the active image has the same size of thumbnail, I don't know what happened. Take a look https://www.extrasocial.it/instagram-followers-reali/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Your question lacks information to get any help from SO users.
Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), learn [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions.
If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and people will be very glad to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, it was a plugin (Fast Velocity Minify). Once deactivated, everything came back to normal. Thank you Mujeebu.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to find out by deactivating other plugin. For time being you can use this code snippet in your active theme functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', array( $this, 'pn_change_product_image_link'), 50, 4 );
function pn_change_product_image_link( $image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon ){
    if( ! is_product() ) return $image; //if not product page
    if( $size == 'shop_thumbnail' ) return $image; // if not gallery thumbnails

    // Your source image link
    $src = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
    $width  = ''; // define the width if needed
    $height = ''; // define the height if needed
    $image  = array( $src, $width, $height );

    return $image;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, the code you gave it to me is not working. When i've added to functions.php all the images of all the products has dissapeared and the dimensions are still small.